# Prevent mounting component if element with id doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am working on a project that uses a form builder (Symfony) to generate forms. In some instances, the below in-house Vue component replaces standard TextArea input's with more flexible html based text editors, based on the input id that is passed in as a prop.

The issue is, in some instances an element with the id `image_id` will not be on the page and as a result generates a slew of javascript errors (as the page is rendered using a template).

Is it possible to **only** mount the `image-uploader` component if there's an element with an id of `#image_id` on the page and prevent the mounting of the component altogether otherwise?

Component Snippet

```
mounted() {
            let DOMInput = document.getElementById(this.inputId);
             //component does stuff if not null
            //need to prevent the mounting of this component altogether if it is null
```

Template

```
<image-uploader input-id="image_id"></image-uploader>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `v-if` directive on the component and render it only if `image_id` is found:

```
<image-uploader input-id="image_id" v-if="condition to check whether image-id exists"></image-uploader>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    idExist: null
  },
  mounted () {
    this.idExist = document.getElementById('test')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="test">test</div>
  <div v-if="idExist">render if test is here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I'm familiar with the v-if directive. That doesn't work well, as I need to add something like `'v-if="document.getElementById('image_id') !== null"` every time I want to instantiate the component, I was hoping to encapsulate that logic in to the component.

Comment: Further, referencing `document` is not allowed in the v-if condition.

Comment: You can calculate the condition in the `mounted` life cycle, update the data property and then put the data property in `v-if` as the condition.

Comment: Interesting thought, I'll give that a try.. thanks for the help

Comment: Yup, that seems to work! Is it possible to somehow add this v-if condition within the component or is that counter productive? Just trying to minimize the code in the template if possible...

Comment: I believe you can have the condition in both the child and parent component, but you have to decide whether to render the component in the parent, so I'd just do it in the parent component probably.

Comment: Yup, I just came to the same conclusion as well, I'll just leave it in the parent. Thank you!